# How can I get the image's id on a ImageView?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, picasso

Is there any way to know the image's id showned on a ImageView on android? My case is: I use Picasso to show image, and if I don't have turned on the connection a default image will be print. Now I wanna make a toast that say: "Turn on the connection to show the image", and I was wondering that I could check the image id.

Comment: Give tag with its id to image view whenever image updated.

Comment: but why do you need the id of the image you are showing ?

Comment: @blackbelt to know if Picasso has drawn: if there is the image from the Internet it means that all is ok, else, I will show a toast with a default image

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately there isn't any method like getDrawableId() or getResourceId() which would allow you to get ID of the resource used in ImageView.

But you can implement a workaround by using `setTag(id)` and `getTag()` to ImageView. Set the tag with id while setting default image and you can get tagged id back by using `getTag()`.